# How do I fix Java's Headless Exception on Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

So I've built a snake game and it worked. 
I wanted to update it with more Java-related technology like Springboot
but when I tried to run the exact same code that worked without Spring,
a Headless Exception has been thrown at me. 
I tried to search online but I haven't found any useful information...

Any idea what caused it?

**The original main method:**

```
package run;

import game.GameFrame;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    new GameFrame();

    }
}
```

**The original GameFrame:**

```
package game;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    public GameFrame(){

        this.add(new GamePanel());
        this.setTitle("Kevin The Snake");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
}
```

**The 'Springboot' main method:**

```
package app.core;

import static app.core.statics.Globals.*;

import app.core.game.GameFrame;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WiseKevinApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WiseKevinApplication.class, args);

        new GameFrame(); // TODO -- Check exceptions (Headless Exception) and maybe try launching GameFrame as an entity

    }

}
```

**The 'Springboot' GameFrame:**

```
package app.core.game;

import javax.swing.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    public GameFrame(){

        this.add(new GamePanel());
        this.setTitle("Wise Kevin");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Spring Boot generally doesn't need all that fancy UI stuff, hence it runs in headless mode. So disable you can disable it on the `SpringApplication` class, by setting `headless` to `false` (the default is `true`). However you aren't really using Spring Boot, as you are doing a `new GameFrame()` which bypasses Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment you call "new" your GameFrame is not under Spring's control.  You would need to create that instance using Spring configuration.

I'd recommend that you read [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-headless-mode).